# PHP Echo from Search Query on HTML Page

Tags: php, jquery, html, echo

I am trying to display search query results on a separate page. I copied the code from a forum, but since the display page isn't php, I'm not sure it will work.

Here is the code from the home page:

```
<form action="search" method="post">
<input type="text" name="q" />
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
</form>
```

I want the search results to show on mysite.com/search   (obviously)

The code on mysite.com/search is as follows:

```
<div id="cse" style="width: 100%;">Loading</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">//
  google.load('jquery', '1');
  google.load('search', '1');
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
    var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('XXXXX');
    customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
    customSearchControl.draw('cse');
    $(".gsc-input").val("<?php echo $_POST['q']; ?>");//insert into search field requested search text
    $(".gsc-search-button").click();//call button click event, show results
  }, true);
// ]]></script>
```

Do I have any options? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

> since the display page isn't php

Then you can't use `$(".gsc-input").val("<?php echo $_POST['q']; ?>");`, but could use something like

```
$.get('path-to-php-script/query.php', function(data) {
   $(".gsc-input").html(data);
   alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

The idea is that you just use jQuery to retrieve and manipulate the data that you need to run through PHP script(s) before they're returned to the HTML-only display page.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive like this 
Put this code in your head tag

```
    <script language="javascript"> 
    function changeData(fromDiv)
    {
        document.getElementById('toDiv').innerHTML = fromDiv.innerHTML;
    }
    </script>
```

And This in your body tag

```
    <div id="toDiv"></div>
    <div id="fromDiv" onclick="changeData(this)">Hello World I am here</div>
```